# npm won't run dev in laravel

Tags: laravel, npm, debian, laravel-mix

I am trying to get my project to work on fresh debian install. npm install works fine, but then npm run dev gives me this:

```
15% building modules 45/46 modules 1 active .../www/html/pms/resources/sass/app.scssnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-12-13T14_03_05_708Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-12-13T14_03_05_720Z-debug.log
```

and the log that this is pointing to looks like this:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@5.8.0
3 info using node@v8.11.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
6 info lifecycle @~dev: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: /usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/html/pms/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: /var/www/html/pms
10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run development' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `npm run development`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:283:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /var/www/html/pms
16 verbose Linux 4.18.0-3-amd64
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v8.11.2
19 verbose npm  v5.8.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ dev: `npm run development`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I'm not sure what should I do, I google adding some npm modules, reinstalling, deleting cache, but I'm not sure what could be the cause. This works on my Windows Laragon machine. I've installed it on Ubuntu without any problem, but on Debian I cannot make it work. Ideas?

Comment: The npm and node versions are a bit out of date.  Might try updating them to more recent versions.  Current LTS of node is 10.14, you're running 8.11, then rebuild.  Looks like you're issue may be with cross-env but I don't see a clear error message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue with this message before the list of npm ERR that you have posted :

> Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X
>   64-bit with Node.js 12.x
>
> Found bindings for the following environments:
>     - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 7.x
>
> This usually happens because your environment has changed since
>   running `npm install`. Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the
>   binding for your current environment.

As you say that you have installed your project on windows and Ubuntu before to try on your fresh Debian install, you maybe have the same problem.